# Python urllib2 - cannot read a page

Tags: python, urllib

I am using `urllib2` in `Python` to scrape a webpage. However, the `read()` method does not return.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://edmonton.en.craigslist.ca/kid/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
f_webpage = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = f_webpage.read()  # <- does not return
```

I last ran the script a month ago and it was working fine then.

Note that the same script runs well for webpages of other categories on Edmonton Craigslist like `http://edmonton.en.craigslist.ca/act/` or `http://edmonton.en.craigslist.ca/eve/`.

Comment: What does "does not return" mean?

Comment: It means that if there is a next statement after that line, it will never get executed.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but might solve your problem. I tried the same URL with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and it works.

Comment: @woozyking: Thank you, the it works fine with `requests` library. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: What does "does not return" mean? Is this python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in comments :)

Install `requests` by `$ pip install requests`

Use `requests` as the following:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://edmonton.en.craigslist.ca/kid/'
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
>>> request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> request.ok
True
>>> request.text  # content in string, similar to .read() in question
...
...
```

Disclaimer: this is not technically the answer to OP's question, but solves OP's problem as `urllib2` is known to be problematic and `requests` library is born to solve such problems.

Answer (score 0):

It returns (or more specifically, errors out) fine for me:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://edmonton.en.craigslist.ca/kid/'
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
>>> request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
>>> f_webpage = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>>> html = f_webpage.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 351, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 541, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 592, in _read_chunked
    value.append(self._safe_read(amt))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 647, in _safe_read
    chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Chances are that Craigslist is detecting that you are a scraper and refusing to give you the actual page.

Comment: That does not seem plausible. I scrape the other categories just fine. Only this category is the problem.

Comment: OK. It appears that this problem only happens for specific categories. Others are scraped fine.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem with you. Part of my error information:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 380, in read
data = self._sock.recv(left)

File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 573, in read
s = self.fp.read(amt)

File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 380, in read
data = self._sock.recv(left)

error: [Errno 10054]
```

I solve it by reading the buffer in small batches instead of reading directly.

```
def readBuf(fsrc, length=16*1024):
    result=''
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        else:
            result+=buf
    return result
```

Instead of using `html=f_webpage.read()`, you can use `html=readBuf(f_webpage)` to scrape the webpage.